# unknown_ca when testing an API

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I installed WSO2 APIM 1.9.0 on Windows Server 2012 with JDK 1.7.0_79.  When I try to test an API with "Try Me," I get "no response from server."  In the console I see an exception "Received fatal alert: unknown_ca".

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using CA signed certs, the browse would not trust the default certs available in https://:8243 So what you need to do is, access https://:8243 from your browser separately and invoke. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a SSL/HTTPS issue .

When testing on the /store , ensure you are on the HTTP port and not HTTPS.(the correct url will be on the log)

So if your offset = 0 , the admin console will be :

```
https://[ip]:9443/carbon
```

and the store :

```
http://[ip]:9763/store
```

If that does not work , paste the Api's HTTPS Request URL in your browser , accept the certificate and try again.

Comment: I tried the steps as above (my auth tokens are not expired and I have tried with both the production and sandbox environments on API store), now the WSO2 API Manager console reports : `WARN - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Missing Credentials` and the API Store web console in the browser shows no content in the response body. `curl` command works though, with `-k` flag from the command line.

Comment: Did you log in and generate a token , or is Auth turned off for your API?